# why am I getting an error when I pass an ifstream&?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, ifstream

I'm trying to code a simple program that uses an ifstream and scanner to read a text file. For some reason I'm getting this error: `"In passing argument 1 of 'bool ReadVector(std::ifstream&, Vector<double>&)'"`. Any idea what I've done wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "scanner.h"
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "vector.h"

// prototype
bool ReadVector(ifstream & infile, Vector<double> & vec);

// main
int main(){
    Vector<double> vec;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("SquareAndCubeRoots.txt");
    if (infile.fail()) Error("Opening file screwed up");
    bool foo = ReadVector(&infile, &vec); // stub
    cout << foo;
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}

// stub
bool ReadVector(ifstream & infile, Vector<double> & vec){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You really don't need `infile.close();` in such cases. It will automatically be called when the `ifstream` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReadVector accepts a reference, but you are giving a pointer. Just call

```
bool foo = ReadVector(infile, vec);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to pass a pointer, while the argument is a reference. Remove address-of operators (`ReadVector(infile, vec)`).